# removing singature in html beautifulsoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, pdf, beautifulsoup, acrobat

i'm tring to parse an etire PDF using beautifulsoup but i'm facing certain issues as the signature is falling inbetween. I use Adobe Acrobat to covert HTML to PDF as it is the closest to preserving the layout.

Converted HTML file : [HTML drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H1eHSFh8NdHJw4IBmzi3Bz8VRT9WgiCD/view?usp=sharing)

[signature to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCqvN.png)

when i parse the li tags to get text, these small 'signature not verified' and other small texts associated with them mix into the text i need.

is there a way to remove them? please help.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

This example will remove (`.extract`) the not needed `<img>` and `<p>` tags from the document:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(open("page.html"), "html.parser")
p = soup.select_one('p:has(img[alt="image"])')

to_delete = []
while True:
    to_delete.append(p)
    if "Reason:" in p.text:
        break
    p = p.find_next_sibling("p")

for p in to_delete:
    p.extract()

print(soup)
```